# Why is my python coding giving runtime error?

Tags: python-3.x

this is my first question in this platform and I'm new to Python coding.and this problem is a challange in HackkerRank.Can you suggest any solution to my coding? It gives runtime error:

```
n=int(input())
phoneBook={}
pb=[]
list1=[]
for i in range(n):
  k=str(input())
  pb.append(k)
  list1.append(k.split(" "))
  for j in range (2):
    phoneBook[list1[i][0]]=list1[i][1]
b='at'
try:
 while b != "":
  b=str(input())
  if any(b in s for s in phoneBook):
   print(b,"=",phoneBook[b],sep='')
  else:
   print("Not found")
except EOFError:
    pass
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: runtime error I have.

Comment: Hackerrank will produce errors for valid code if it takes to long - is this the "runtime" you are talking about? if so: optimize your solution to be faster.

Comment: what is the hackerrank url for the problem?

Comment: i guess it is due to optimization,there are 1000 inputs which is entered in compilation.so what should I do,should I change for loops to something?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps/problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortened code - you are using far too many intermediate lists - they all take time to construct, fill and use:

```
# create the phone book
d = {}
for n in range(int(input())):

    # repeat input() and strip/split/strip it into the dict
    # use list decomposition instead of a list over a range of indext list values
    name,number = [x.strip() for x in input().strip().split()]
    d[name]=number

# read and produce numbers until done
while True:
    try:
        q = input()

        # no need for if any(b in s for s in phoneBook):
        # dictionary is fast for testing if key in it
        # I would prefer dict.get(key,default) but for the wanted 
        # output this is easier / better
        if q in d:
            # use string formating
            print("{}={}".format(q, d[q]))
        else:
            print("Not found")
    except EOFError:
        break
```